# Hibernate annotations to map one to one unidirectional association with composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one, composite-primary-key

I have two tables : report and flyleaf. A report is identified by an 'id' and an 'index' which are foreign and primary keys in flyleaf table.

The schema of the tables are :

```
CREATE TABLE `report` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `index` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
   `nb_page` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
); 
ALTER TABLE `report` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`index`);

CREATE TABLE `flyleaf_t` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `index` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
   `title` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
   `author` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
   `checker` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE `flyleaf` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`index`);
ALTER TABLE `flyleaf` ADD CONSTRAINT `flyleaf_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`,`index`) REFERENCES `report` (`id`, `index`);
```

I use Hibernate annotation to map this association in unidirectional way. When I use a simple keys(non composite) it works well obviously, but when I try to use composite keys an "org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException" is thrown with the message : "Provided id of the wrong type for class lgmi_cr.Flyleaf. Expected: class lgmi_cr.Flyleaf, got class lgmi_cr.Report"

If someone already saw the same case or have an idea about how to represent this association in unidirectional one-to-one way, its help will be appreciated.

**EDIT :** This is how Id did the mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name="report")
public class Report implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "index")
    private String index;

    @OneToOne 
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id"),
            @JoinColumn(name="index", referencedColumnName="index")})
    private Flyleaf flyleaf;
...

@Entity
@Table(name="flyleaf")
public class Flyleaf implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "index")
    private String index;
....
```

And I got this exception "org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class lgmi_cr.Flyleaf. Expected: class lgmi_cr.Flyleaf, got class lgmi_cr.Report"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish you could share how you're mapping these relationships in Hibernate? This is how I would do it:

1) Map each composite table as a separate class object using @Embeddable annotation, e.g:

```
@Embeddable
public class ReportPK implements Serializable {

  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name="id")
  private int id;
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name="index")
  private String index;
...
```

And the entity class would look like:

```
@Table(name="report")
public class Report implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  protected ReportPK id;
...
```

2) In the flyleaf entity class, you can add the unidirectional mapping as:

```
@OneToOne
  @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="id",
      referencedColumnName="id"),
    @JoinColumn(name="index",
      referencedColumnName="index"),
  })
  private Report report;
...
```

Perhaps you can be more specific if this doesn't help. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help @nkmuturi. Your solution works and I inverse the unidirectional mapping (map a flyleaf in a report). Would you please give more details about the code and the used mechanism (I am new using hibernate)?

Comment: The Id annotation is used for mapping to tables containing a single primary key. However, for tables with composite primary keys, IdClass or Embeddable are used. See further explanation here http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity and this ebook http://www.ebooks.com/602765/beginning-hibernate/linwood-jeff-minter-dave/ for even more.

Comment: I have just start reading this book and I find it very interesting. I have just another question, with this annotations when I remove a report, does the associated flyleaf will be removed automatically or I have to add some cascade parameters?
With your answer I think the question is answered.

Comment: Yes, you can add @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) on your Report entity to auto-delete flyleaf record. :-)