# Hibernate AnnotationException: mappedBy reference

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

There are lots of questions about this in StackOverflow. But l still can't solve it.
I am coding a tax system using Hibernate as my persistence layer.
Now, l have two entity classes:
Role.java and RolePrivilege.java.
this is Role.java

```
package com.taxsys.nsfw.role.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
@Entity
@Table(name="role")
public class Role implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="pk_hilo", strategy="hilo")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="pk_hilo")
    @Column(name="role_id")
    private String roleId;

    @Column(name="role_name",length=32, nullable=false)
    private String roleName;

    @Column(name="state", length=1)
    private String state;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=RolePrivilege.class, 
    mappedBy="role", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, 
    fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<RolePrivilege> role = new HashSet<>();


    public static String ROLE_STATE_VALID = "1";
    public static String ROLE_STATE_INVALID = "0";


    public Set<RolePrivilege> getRolePrivilege() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRolePrivilege(Set<RolePrivilege> rolePrivilege) {
        this.role = rolePrivilege;
    }
    public String getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }
    public void setRoleId(String roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }
    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }
    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public Role() {
    }
    public Role(String roleId, String roleName, String state, Set<RolePrivilege> rolePrivilege) {
        super();
        this.roleId = roleId;
        this.roleName = roleName;
        this.state = state;
        this.role = rolePrivilege;
    }
}
```

this is RolePrivilege.java:

```
package com.taxsys.nsfw.role.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="role_privilege")
public class RolePrivilege implements Serializable{

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Role.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="role_id")
    @Id
    private Role role;

    @Id
    private String code;

    public RolePrivilege(Role role, String code) {
        super();
        this.role = role;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public RolePrivilege() {
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((code == null) ? 0 : code.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((role == null) ? 0 : role.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        RolePrivilege other = (RolePrivilege) obj;
        if (code == null) {
            if (other.code != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!code.equals(other.code))
            return false;
        if (role == null) {
            if (other.role != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!role.equals(other.role))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

I am using Hibernate3.6,spring3.0,struts2.3 and tomcat7.
But when l start Tomcat, the error message will be showing:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.taxsys.nsfw.role.entity.RolePrivilege.role in com.taxsys.nsfw.role.entity.Role.role
```

Look my code! mappedBy="role".It's the same with RolePrivilege.role!And even if l use lower-case, it doesn't work! I don't know why. Maybe it is a question about jar or compatibility? Thank you!

Comment: does the role_id in RolePrivilege need to be part of the primary key?

Comment: Did you try removing the targetEntity annotation?Still the same error?

Comment: l regard Role Object and code(String) as composite keys. pay attention, not role_id,is Role object. it's right?  i am reading a book, the book mention the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove @Id in RolePrivilege.java for `private Role role;` and report back what error are u still getting

Comment: Thank you very much！No Problem! but l have a question.that is,in RolePrivilege ,l want to let Role and code as composite keys,and what should l do? Look my RolePrivilege.java. I user two @Id on role and code,but it's error! and other way？

Comment: accept my answer if it worked for you.
About composite keys, your approach is wrong, have a look at how to setup keys in manyToMany relationship, it uses the same concept

Answer (score 0):

You can map the composite key using @Embeddable annotation in a new class object, then use @ManyToOne mapping to map the child object to the parent object. See [Hibernate annotations to map one to one unidirectional association with composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840293/hibernate-annotations-to-map-one-to-one-unidirectional-association-with-composit/42841153#42841153)